# Having problem with this form and the select option and also the email is not send

Tags: codeigniter

I want this form to send email but i don't work, i don'y know where is the problem but i think the problem is in the model, also this form has a select function i cannot make it work when i choose something in the select option to send it with email

This is the controller

```
    <?php

defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Offer extends CI_Controller {
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->load->model('admin_model');
        $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url', 'text'));
    }

    public function index() {
                $this->load->view('header.php');
                $this->load->view('offer.php');
                $this->load->view('footer.php');


    }

    public function sendOffer(){
         if(isset($_POST['companyname']) && isset($_POST['sendername']) && isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['number']) && isset($_POST['interest']) && isset($_POST['message'])){

            $data['companyname'] = $_POST['companyname'];
            $data['sendername'] = $_POST['sendername'];
            $data['email'] = $_POST['email'];
            $data['number'] = $_POST['number'];
            $data['interest'] = $_POST['interest'];
            $data['message'] = $_POST['message'];
            $data['created_at'] = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

           $this->admin_model->sendOfferEmail($data);
          $this->db->insert('offer',$data);
            $true = "Message Sent Successfully ...";
            $this->session->set_flashdata('true', $true);
            redirect(base_url()."offer");
         }else{
            $error = "Failed To Send, Please check all inputs and try again !!!";
            $this->session->set_flashdata('error', $error);
            redirect(base_url()."offer");
         }
    }


}
```

This is the model

```
    public function sendOfferEmail($data){
        $MailTo = "menna.ashour@thetranslationgate.com";

        $subject = "The Translation Gate Website offer".$data['created_at'];

        $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
        $headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";
        //$headers .= "Cc: amr.hussein@europelocalize.com". "\r\n";
        $headers .= 'From: The Translation Gate Website'."\r\n";
        $message = '<!DOCTYPE html>
                    <html lang="en">
                    <head>
                        <meta charset="utf-8">
                        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
                        <meta name="description" content="">
                        <meta name="author" content="">
                        <title>Falaq| Site Manager</title>
                        <style>
                        body {
                            font-family: "Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
                            font-size: 14px;
                            line-height: 1.428571429;
                            color: #333;
                        }
                        section#unseen
                        {
                            overflow: scroll;
                            width: 100%
                        }
                        </style>
                        <!--Core js-->
                    </head>

                    <body>
                        <div class="panel-body">
                                <div class="adv-table editable-table ">
                                    <div class="clearfix">
                                        <div class="btn-group">
                                            <span class=" btn-primary" style="">
                                            </span>
                                        </div>

                                    </div>

                                    <div class="space15"></div>

                                    <table class="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered" id="" style="overflow:scroll;border: 1px solid;width: 100%;text-align: center">
                                            <tbody>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td style="background-color: #ddd;">Company Name</td>
                                                <td style="background-color: #f9f9f9;">'.$data['companyname'].'</td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                 <td style="background-color: #ddd;">Full Name</td>
                                                <td style="background-color: #f9f9f9;">'.$data['sendername'].'</td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                 <td style="background-color: #ddd;">Email</td>
                                                <td style="background-color: #f9f9f9;">'.$data['email'].'</td>
                                            </tr>
                                              <tr>
                                                 <td style="background-color: #ddd;">Phone Number</td>
                                                <td style="background-color: #f9f9f9;">'.$data['number'].'</td>
                                            </tr>

                                            <tr>
                                                 <td style="background-color: #ddd;">Message</td>
                                                <td style="background-color: #f9f9f9;">'.$data['message'].'</td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                </div>
                          </div>
                    </body>
                    </html>';
        mail($MailTo,$subject,$message,$headers);
    }



    public function getInterest($interest){
        $result = $this->get_where('interest',array('id' => $interest))->row();
        if(isset($result->name)){
            return $result->name;
        }else{
            return '';
        }
     }
 }
 ?>
```

This is the view

```
<section id="pageBar">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <h1 class="page-title pull-left">Offers</h1>
                <ol class="breadcrumb pull-right">
                  <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>                  
                  <li>Offers</li>
                </ol>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>

    <!-- Page-Bar -->   

    <!-- Login Form -->

    <div id="login">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2 col-xs-offset-0">
                    <form class="login-form" method="post" action="<?=base_url()?>offer/sendOffer" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                        <div class="form-group input-block">
                            <label for="name">Company Name</label>
                            <input type="text" name="companyname" class="form-control" id="companyname" required>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group input-block">
                            <label for="name">Full Name</label>
                            <input type="text" name="sendername" class="form-control" id="sendername" required>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group input-block">
                            <label for="email" style="top: 24px; font-size: 16px;">Email</label>
                            <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" id="email" required="" autocomplete="off">
                        </div>
                      <div class="form-group input-block">
                            <label for="name" style="top: 24px; font-size: 16px;">Phone Number</label>
                            <input type="text" name="number" class="form-control" id="number" required="" autocomplete="off">
                        </div>
                        <div class="select-group">
                             <select class="form-control selectpicker" >
                                <option disabled="disabled" selected="" value="">Interest</option>
                                <option value="1">Arabic</option>
                                <option value="2">DTP</option>
                                <option value="3">Both</option>
                                </select>

                        </div>


                        <div class="">
                            <textarea name="message" id="message" class="form-control" rows="6" placeholder="Message" required="" autocomplete="off"></textarea>
                        </div>
                        <div class="text-center">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-gray">
                                Submit  
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </form> </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [This form cannot send email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54948693/this-form-cannot-send-email)

Answer (score 0):

You have disabled to blank value the select box.So you are not able select.
Remove disabled="disabled" from select box.
For mail service turn on development mode and check the error you got.

Comment: what is development mode and how i turn it on??

Comment: In development mode you can see the PHP as well other errors.
In your codeigniter project find the index.php file change the environment like below-

define('ENVIRONMENT', 'development');